# Best translation for "Zine"

Tags: traducción

I am trying to figure out the best translation for ["zine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zine). I have found “revista independiente.” Or I could describe it in Spanish and keep it as "zine." Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Although the DLE does not recognise it the term *zine* is the one used by the [Spanish Wikipedia for its article on the subject](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zine). The DLE sometimes lags behind modern Spanish usage.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just stick with "zine" and maybe describe it. Sometimes translating, in my experience, isn't the best option - it just doesn't hold the same weight in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi punto de vista no es necesario que realice una traducción del significado de "**zine**", si bien lo que puede hacer es un comentario explicativo o reseña aclarando el significado actual de una palabra menos conocida, ya que "**zine**" es la abreviatura de "magazine o "fanzine", palabras estás ya reconocidas en lengua española y por tanto no necesarias de traducir;

- "magacin" https://dle.rae.es/magac%C3%ADn

**Magacín**

Tb. *magazín*.

Del ingl. magazine, y este del fr. magasin.

1. m. Publicación periódica con artículos de diversos autores, dirigida al público en general.
2. m. Espacio de televisión o radio de contenido muy variado.

---

- "fancine" https://dle.rae.es/fanzine

**Fanzine**

Del ingl. amer. fanzine, y este acrón. de fan magazine; literalmente 'revista para fanes'.

1. m. Revista de escasa tirada y distribución, hecha con pocos medios por aficionados a temas como el cómic, la ciencia ficción, el cine, la música pop, etc.

Cuando escriba la palabra "zine", puede indicar su significado con paréntesis o una llamada a pie de página;

(texto)..... **zine** (abreviatura de magazine o fanzine)....(texto).

Bella, bienvenida a la comunidad.

---

---

> From my point of view, it is not necessary for you to translate the
> meaning of "**zine**", although what you can do is an explanatory
> comment or review clarifying the current meaning of a lesser-known
> word, since "** zine**" is the abbreviation for "magazine or
> "fanzine", words that are already recognized in the Spanish language
> and therefore unnecessary to translate;
>
> - "magacin" https://dle.rae.es/magac%C3%ADn
>
> **Magacín**
>
> Tb. *magazín*.
>
> Del ingl. magazine, y este del fr. magasin.
>
> 1. m. Publicación periódica con artículos de diversos autores, dirigida al público en general.
> 2. m. Espacio de televisión o radio de contenido muy variado.
>
> ---
>
> - "fancine" https://dle.rae.es/fanzine
>
> **Fanzine**
>
> Del ingl. amer. fanzine, y este acrón. de fan magazine; literalmente
> 'revista para fanes'.
>
> 1. m. Revista de escasa tirada y distribución, hecha con pocos medios por aficionados a temas como el cómic, la ciencia ficción, el cine, la
>    música pop, etc.
>
> ---
>
> When you type the word "zine," you can indicate its meaning with
> parentheses or a callout at the bottom of the page;
>
> (text)..... **zine** (abbreviation for magazine or fanzine)....(text).

> (text)..... **zine** (abreviatura de magazine o fanzine) ....(text).

**P.D.**

Bella, welcome to the community.